# jquery prop checked on dynamically created elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

Doing some dynamic stuff with my rails app here, creating contacts from the database and append them to a div. I learned already that I have to use the `on 'click'` handler to listen to dynamically created elements:

coffeescript

```
$(document.body).on 'click','.js--toggle-contact-item', ->
   id = $(this).data("id")

   if !$(".js--checkbox-"+id).is(':checked')
       console.log "its not checked"
      $(".js--checkbox-"+id).prop("checked",true)
   else
      console.log "its checked"
      $(".js--checkbox-"+id).prop("checked",false)
```

the function works for both: dynamic and non dynamic elements.
However, the `prop` function does not listen and won't work means I see the console log *"its not checked"* but then the prop event does not fire.

It works also perfect on non-dynamic but not for dynamic.

What can I do to also make the prop function firing?

Comment: Read about [`Event delegation`](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: could you provide a jsfidle example?

Comment: try `$(".js--checkbox-"+id).prop("checked","checked")`

Comment: @AmolUdage not working

Comment: ok, can you add `$(".js--checkbox-"+id)` result?

Comment: also add your html : -)

Comment: It says: ```[prevObject: jQuery.fn.init[1], context: document, selector: ".js--checkbox-110"]```

Comment: On the working prop fire it says ```[input.checkbox.js--checkbox-106, prevObject: jQuery.fn.init[1], context: document, selector: ".js--checkbox-106"]```

Comment: what do u mean `working prop fire`??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113044/discussion-between-amol-udage-and-donmb).